# How do I remove spaced before and after commas in a csv file using python?

Tags: python, regex, csv

Currently one row of my csv file looks like this :

> 314523, 165538,    76255, 335416, 416827 1250536:1 1744638:1 298526:1 1568238:1

I need it to look like this :

> 314523,165538,76255,335416,416827 1250536:1 1744638:1 298526:1 1568238:1

I only want to **remove the spaces after or before commas** and leave the other blank spaces as it is.

How can I do this in python?

Note : I am a beginner in python

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend using the replace function. You enter the pattern you want to replace. In your example, the pattern is comma space `(', ')` and space comma `(' ,')`. Then say what you want to replace the pattern with `(',')`.

```
line=line.replace(', ', ',').replace(' ,',',')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex to do this, for a string:

```
import re
outputstring = re.sub(r'\s*,\s*', ',', inputstring)
```

This regex matches the whitespace surrounding a comma and the comma, and replaces it with just a comma. For a file, just do this for each line.

Comment: `re.sub(r'\s*,\s*', ',', inputstring)`, since your regex expects atleast one space before comma.

Comment: You regex isn't correct. It will not match `foo, bar` and will not match `foo ,bar`